# Disabled product still displaying on frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, inventory

Good day all.

I am experiencing an issue regarding disabled simple products that is associated with a configurable product. The product still shows in the list of options on the frontend when looking at the configurable product. Is there any way this can be prevented without manually unlinking the simple product from the configurable product?

**Edit**

We use an Apptha extension to handle our out of stock mail subscription. Is there a possibility the extension could cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The out of stock extension is only for the users to register and get alerts when the product is back in stock. This has no relation with simple products showing in frontend.